# How to make a multiple bar chart?

Tags: python, streamlit, altair, grouped-bar-chart

How to make a bar chart using 'altair' to use the information in a table?

If you need to change the table format is it ok, I want to make a bar chart as below.
(My end goal is to create a bar chart in streamlit.)

Example,

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame([['sst', '100', '1000'],['can','500','600']], columns=['model','0','1'])
st.bar_chart(df, ??)
```

[image]

[image: How to make a this chart?]

Comment: What is really your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I changed the question to more detail, I just want to make a bar chart using the information in the table.

Comment: Why are you putting numbers as strings in the DataFrame?

Comment: The easiest plot is to directly plot `df`: `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='model')` providing the numbers are numbers, not strings.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Changed to the question of using 'altair' to create a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

as step 1 - you need to melt your dataframe, so that it would consist only of 3 columns, model, variable (0/1) and value.
Step 2 - Grouped bar chart - is nothing than 2 individual bar charts for each model, stack together as columns.

Step 3 - final tweaks:
Additional chart configuration to make it look as a single chart:

- spacing between 2 columns - here it is 0.
- Padding inside each chart - to add some breathing space between models and keeping grid lines at the same time
- with a stroke opacity =0 - we remove frames around each chart to keep an impression of a single image.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

df = pd.DataFrame([['sst', '100', '1000'],['can','500','600']], columns=['model','0','1'])

#transform dataframe 
source=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['model'])

chart=alt.Chart(source).mark_bar(strokeWidth=100).encode(
    x=alt.X('variable:N', title="", scale=alt.Scale(paddingOuter=0.5)),#paddingOuter - you can play with a space between 2 models 
    y='value:Q',
    color='variable:N',
    column=alt.Column('model:N', title="", spacing =0), #spacing =0 removes space between columns, column for can and st 
).properties( width = 300, height = 300, ).configure_header(labelOrient='bottom').configure_view(
    strokeOpacity=0)

st.altair_chart(chart) #, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]